# UK PLAB Visa Refusal due to unexplained bank deposits

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I had applied for a PLAB (Doctors) Visa for the UK to appear in PLAB test.
I got refused on the basis of two recent large deposits in the bank statement I provided (my mothers).
In reality, these are my own savings which I had deposited in her account to make it more strong.
The only objection I got was that I must provide evidence for the source of these deposits.
Other than this, I have previously travelled to the UK and USA as well as other parts of the world and my travel history is fine.
Can someone please advise on how to proceed and re-apply?

Comment: This is a very common case. Large transactions on the bank accounts near visa application dates are always a red flag scenario and good grounds for refusal. `I got refused on the basis of two recent large deposits in the bank statement I provided (my mothers)` Could you clarify what you did here ? Why did you provide your mother's bank statements ?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input.
I am currently unemployed which is the reason my mother will support me for this exam and trip. This is also why I showed her bank statement. The two large deposits (about 1400 GBP each) were my own savings in cash which I had deposited in her account last month. Do you think it is advisable for her to get a letter from her office stating that those payments were her housing allowance? Or is it better for me to tell the truth and say that those payments were my own savings from my previous job? Many thanks!

Comment: You should always tell the truth (and provide every available evidence for it). Had you done so previously, you might well have been approved for the visa.

Answer (score 9):

## Update 19 July 2015

In April 2015 new visitor rules activated as a result of the on-going [Simplification Project](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/238514/7730.pdf).  The text cited below was replaced with text that makes the rules easier to understand.  The new rules are at [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423477/20150424_mmigration_rules_app_v_final_v2.pdf), and the operative text is in Paragraph V 4.2 (e).

> ...must have sufficient funds...

Simpler.  Easier to understand.  But a whole lot more nuanced and subtle...

The press release is at [Changes to the UK's Visa Services](https://www.gov.uk/government/world-location-news/changes-to-the-uks-visa-service).

All of the same principles put forward in the original answer still apply, and decision-makers still use the same criteria to assess an applicant's credibility.

---

## Original Answer

Your bank accounts suggested that you were using a 'funds parking' strategy, and the ECO challenged your credibility as a result; hence a refusal.  They also consider the parking strategy to be a mild form of deception, which commensurately damages your credibility.

Briefly, the 'funds parking' strategy involves having a friend or relative inflate your account by giving you a temporary loan which you repay after the visa has been issued.  But when they detect this strategy, they are entitled to refuse on Paragraph 41 (vi), which says in part

```
will maintain and accommodate himself and any dependants adequately out of resources
available to him
```

with emphasis on 'available to him'.  You used your mother's bank account, which defies this rule in the first instance because you need to show the funds are available to you.  Had they wanted to, they could have refused on that ground alone.  Those arrangements need to be rigorously explained.

In your case, the irregular deposits came from transferring funds from another account which belongs to you.  This can be overcome by simply including an explanatory note along with the other statements such that the debits from one account agree with the credits in the other account.  This makes the provenance of the funds clear.

In the comments below your question, you ask if you should compound the problems by lying.  At the moment, your history now contains a refusal suggesting credibility issues.  If you get caught lying in a subsequent application, your credibility will be further damaged.  If and when your credibility becomes depleted, you will be locked in to refusals on that ground alone.