# Reapply or appeal UK visa

Tags: uk, pakistani-citizens, visa-refusals

I am from Pakistan. I had applied for a UK visa for my plab (medical) examination, but my visa was refused due to sudden influx of money in my father's bank statement and secondly as I am unemployed, so my ECO thinks that I would not return back home. Now I am thinking of re-applying with my mother's bank statement and showing some property in my name. Should I re-apply or appeal?

Comment: How long ago was it? Do you have a good reason for the 'sudden influx of money' - because that's the part you're going to have to explain if you appeal...

Comment: @mkennedy Previous question has mother's bank account and this has father's. Quite fishy or maybe true also.

Answer (score 1):

You were refused a UK PLAB visa (Paragragh 75 of the Immigration Rules) because of an apparent 'funds parking' gambit (see [UK PLAB Visa Refusal due to unexplained bank deposits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42820/uk-plab-visa-refusal/43122#43122) for definitions), and you want to know if you should make a fresh application or appeal.

The answer here is quite straight-forward because a PLAB refusal does not attract appeal rights.  This would have been explained in your refusal notice.  Attempting to appeal when there is no right would demonstrate to them that you do not understand the rules and may damaged future applications.

The remaining option is to make a fresh application.  You can use the advice previously given in [UK PLAB Visa Refusal due to unexplained bank deposits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42820/uk-plab-visa-refusal/43122#43122) as a guideline.

Comment: ........so can i use my mother's bank statement this time........bec i dont have a proper expalanation for my father"s bank statement. Thanx

Comment: @zain, yes. Perilous, but yes of course you may use different bank statements next time.  Tricky one overall...

Comment: y risky.would they disapprove it or ban me. something like that

Comment: As an afterthought, why don't you transfer the amount to your bank account and mention these are the funds provided by my parents for my upkeep ? Maybe fine, maybe not. The only thing to prove in that case would be where did you get the money from, rather than having to prove it's my parent's money and they have allowed me to use it or something.

Comment: @DumbCoder, brilliant idea!  Make an answer from that.

Comment: @zain, it's not a forum here. Vote on this answer and move on please.